# Add external components in the constraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

How can we add components from external libraries directly in the android studio layout designer and constraint them?

Example:
This is not provided as a component you can drag to the design editor

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
 android:id=”@+id/login_button”
 android:layout_width=”wrap_content”
 android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that's missing from your example is the constraints that Android Studio places in the ui widgets for you. I recommend playing around with constraint layout by adding and moving around some of the pre-defined widgets and inspecting the generated code. The constraints are pretty easy to understand so you'll be able pick it up quite quickly.